# show current line number and max line count in title bar

Tags: frame-title-format

I managed to display the current buffer and complete file path in the title bar with the following snippet

```
(setq frame-title-format
                            '(buffer-file-name "%b - %f" ; File buffer
                          '(line-number-at-pos
                                             )))
```

But the line-number-at-pos does not work, i.e. the current line number is not displayed. What am I doing wrong here?

Also, is there an efficient way to display the lines of code in the currently visited file as well?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting that the %l is indeed ignored for the frame-title-format. But you can wrap `line-number-at-pos` in an eval form and return a string:

```lisp
(setq frame-title-format
      '("%b - %f " (:eval (number-to-string (line-number-at-pos)))))

;; To have it working on line change you have to add this to post-command-hook:
(add-hook 'post-command-hook
          #'(lambda () (setq frame-title-format
      '("%b - %f " (:eval (number-to-string (line-number-at-pos)))))))

;; To add total line count, use this instead (remove above hook first)
(add-hook 'post-command-hook
          #'(lambda () (setq frame-title-format
      '("%b - %f " (:eval (number-to-string (line-number-at-pos))) ":"
        (:eval (number-to-string (count-lines (point-min) (point-max))))))))
```

To display lines of code you can activate `display-line-numbers-mode`.

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately this does not update dynamically but only upon certain actions like e.g. isearch

Comment: as for the total number of lines per file, I dont want to have visual noise in the form of a large column with line numbers but rather one integer which specifies the total line numbers

Comment: see a working example now. Since changing the line numbers dynamically requires a refresh, you have to somehow add the the expression to a hook

Comment: many thanks good sir!

Comment: still does not update upon using c-n and c-p oO

Comment: That seems to be because of optimizations in the C display code xdisp.c, so the frame title format is not being updated despite the `frame-title-format` being changed. Also, it does update using C-n and C-p. It doesn't in a small subset of circumstances, like empty lines at the end of a file. Open an Emacs issue at emacs-devel.

Comment: `force-mode-line-update` should also update the frame title. You can add it in the `post-command-hook`, maybe add a condition to only run it after `C-n` and `C-p`. Also make sure that it runs after setting the format (by passing an appropriate 'depth' argument to `add-hook`).

Comment: @dalanicolai Could you please post a working example with your last comments? I am struggling with the same issue.

Comment: @onlycparra Well, the simple way would be to add `(add-hook 'post-command-hook #'force-mode-line-update 90)` AFTER the code in the answer. If you would like to add conditions, then you could do that in a separate function and add that function to the hook instead. However, I guess you can perfectly fine start without adding the conditions, and maybe add them later, when you know how things work.